# How to create a widget with tabview?

Tags: swift, view, swipe, tabview, widgetkit

Like in this example:

[image: Widget with swipe-able view]

I have tried TabView but that just caused the app to crash.

Comment: Only the user can do that. Widgets can only have tappable areas that open the app. That is made by the user dragging widgets on top of each other

Comment: Oh what a shame. I thought it is something that you can code in. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is something that the user can do only by stacking widgets on top of each other. It is not something you can code in the app itself.

Comment: Yes, these are smart stacks, you need to donate intents to make your app available for smart stacks. Not all apps are available in the Smart Stack so you could read about donating intents